# Load routes only after user logged in

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I'm developing an AngularJS app where security is a big concern. I'm wondering if I could implement the following architecture:

I want to have only the login route available at start, and then, after user is logged in, my rest API provides a list of allowed routes and the app registers that routes.

That's because I don't want to expose all the routes in the code to avoid someone messing with it and trying to acces routes that are only accessible by authorized users. I know I can implement filters to only allow access to certain routes, but I don't want to expose the protected ones (in the code) at all.

Is this approach correct? Is there a way to implement it?

Comment: If you don't want to expose the routes at all then you might consider using server side login page that then loads angular app. Doesn't necessarily need to involve a redirect ... just output applicable html/js depending on server determining auth status

Comment: @charlietfl I understand, but I don't want to use server side code. I want the frontend to only have static content that could be served by a CDN.

Comment: In that case there really isn't any way to completely prevent access to the scripts and therefore the route url's since even if you lazy load scripts the url's for them would need to be in main script used. With that being said you can certianly prevent data being delivered from API for unauthorized users

Answer (score 0):

Your best decision (in my opinion) is to build 2 separate angular's app: First for Sign In/ Sign Up, Forgot password, Second one for private stuff.

For this reason you should use 2 separate html files (server-based routing I guess) with different list of `.js` files. Private `index.html` should be protected against direct access from the server side.

Also, keep in mind that you can load `js` files dynamically.